# How to convert a time to UTC and then device local time

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting following time from service

> 'Nov 11 2019 7:30 PM'

I know this is US Central Time, I need to get hours between current time and this event time, but i am unable to understand how to convert this date to UTC.

I am using following approach, but this does not seem to be working fine.

```
public Date ticketJSONDateFormatter(String dateTime){
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter
            = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy HH:mm a");
    
    Date parsedDate = null;
    try {
        simpleDateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        parsedDate = simpleDateFormatter.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parsedDate;
}
```

This method returns following `date`

```
Fri Oct 11 12:30:00 GMT+05:00 2019
```

Although the expected output may be something like this. My device is at (+5:00 UTC)

```
Fri Oct 12 12:30:00 GMT+05:00 2019
```

Comment: which version of Java you are using? The reason I asked is Java >= 8 provide feature rich date-dime api.

Comment: @techtabu:  java 8

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

You can get this in following steps:

1. Use [ZonedDateTime.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to parse the time you are receiving.
2. Convert the America Central time to your local time.
3. Get your current time.
4. Find the difference between your current time and the event time converted to your local.

Example:

```
    // Parsing the time you are receiving in Central Time Zone. Using Chicago as a representative Zone.
    String dateWithZone = "Nov 11 2019 7:30 PM".concat("America/Chicago") ;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu h:m aVV");

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateWithZone, formatter);
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime); // This is the time you received in Central time zone.

    // Now convert the event time in your local time zone
    ZonedDateTime eventTimeInLocal = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    // Then find the duration between your current time and event time
    System.out.println(Duration.between(ZonedDateTime.now(), eventTimeInLocal).toHours());
```

The duration class provides many other utilities methods to get more precise duration.

Comment: @OleV.V. You are absolutely correct. I misread and was probably confused with `unable to understand how to convert this date to UTC`. I updated my example now. There is no need to convert the time to UTC for what trying to be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LocalDateTime' to parse the string to date,

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");
String date = "Nov 11 2019 07:30 PM";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

Then convert it to your preferred zone,

```java
Instant cdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).toInstant();
return cdt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

This will return an `Instant`.

And as Ole V.V suggested in the comment, I wouldn't recommend using old `Date` and `Calendar` API. I would suggest reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969651/1257729) to understand the issues associated with the old `Date` API.